# A Webpage element is not getting picked up when I use Beautiful soup and python to crawl the page

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

[The product page highlights the class for the price, other items are working except for picking price from this class.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6F4xv.png)

```
try:
    price = soup.find("span", attrs={'class':'PriceBoxPlanOption__offer-price___3v9x8 PriceBoxPlanOption__offer-price-cp___2QPU_'}).string.strip().replace(',', '').replace('₹','')
    # we are omitting unnecessary spaces
    # and commas form our string
except AttributeError:
    price = "NA"
print("Products price = ", price)
```

Product Link: https://www.1mg.com/otc/iodex-ultra-gel-otc716295
the below class is not returning any value, but it should

```
class = PriceBoxPlanOption__offer-price___3v9x8 PriceBoxPlanOption__offer-price-cp___2QPU_
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this has worked for me with slight edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will get you the result you want:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers= {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.get('https://www.1mg.com/otc/iodex-ultra-gel-otc716295', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
elem = soup.select_one('.PriceBoxPlanOption__offer-price___3v9x8.PriceBoxPlanOption__offer-price-cp___2QPU_')
print(elem.text)
```

Result:

```
₹171
```

Docs for BeautifulSoup can be found at https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-value-true